# Error while converting string to datetime format c#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am unable to convert string to datetime.

Here is the code:

```
string[] itemIDList = null,
brandIdList = null,
indentItemIdList = null,
qtyList = null,
requiredDateList = null;

itemIDList = form["ItemId"].Split(',');
brandIdList = form["BrandId"].Split(',');
indentItemIdList = form["IndentItemId"].Split(',');
qtyList = form["Qty"].Split(',');
requiredDateList = form["RequiredDate"].Split(',');

//int fId = 0;
//selected fields
int cSelCount = 0;
if (itemIDList != null)
{
    foreach (string itemField in itemIDList)
    {
        string indentitemId = indentItemIdList[cSelCount] == "" 
            ? "0" 
            : indentItemIdList[cSelCount];

        string brandField = brandIdList[cSelCount];
        string qtyField = qtyList[cSelCount];

        DateTime requiredDateFiled = requiredDateList[cSelCount] == "" 
            ? DateTime.Now 
            : DateTime.ParseExact(requiredDateList[cSelCount], "dd-MM-yyyy", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemField) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandField) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qtyField) && 
            qtyField != "0" && qtyField != "")
        {
            IndentItemModel objIndentItem = new IndentItemModel();
            objIndentItem.IndentItemId = Convert.ToInt32(indentitemId);
            objIndentItem.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(itemField);
            objIndentItem.BrandId = Convert.ToInt32(brandField);
            objIndentItem.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(qtyField);
            objIndentItem.ItemStatusId = Convert.ToInt32(ItemStatus.Indent);
            objIndentItem.RequiredDate = Convert.ToDateTime(requiredDateFiled);
            objIndentItem.CreatedBy = objIndentItem.ModifiedBy = objModel.ModifiedBy;
            objIndentItem.ModifiedDate = objIndentItem.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            indentItemList.Add(objIndentItem);
        }

        cSelCount++;
    }
}
```

Error message:

[image: Error message]

The same formatting code is working outside the foreach loop.. I hope this doesn't matter with foreach loop but some where I missed some thing.. please help me out to get resolved

[changed my code to this format but still had the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91atg.png)

My sys date foramt is mm-dd-yy and i am parsing to dd-MM-yyyy..

Comment: Can you give a sample value of `requiredDateList[cSelCount]`? It could be that one of the values is an exception to that, so try using `TryParseExact`

Comment: IF the string looks like dateTime ,why just keep it the way it is ? Or,if u could provide the date,i can post an answer

Comment: Is `requiredDateList[cSelCount].ToString()` at that point in dd-MM-yyyy format? Presumably not.

Comment: @Sunil value is "03-27-2018"

Comment: @john may be not it may varie based on the system datetime format. my sys datetime foramt is dd-MM-yyy..

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? The date you specified [works in my test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NWfr8C). ParseExact will work only if the date is exactly in the format you have provided. If you have provided a different format date, it will not work. The only conclusion here is that the date you provided is not in the format you expect. Note that even adding a space to the string will cause ParseExact to fail.

Comment: Why do you do `Convert.ToDateTime(requiredDateFiled);` when `requiredDateFiled` is already a `DateTime`?

Comment: @RufusL yeah there is no use to convert again.. I have updated my code..

Comment: Look at the value of `requiredDateList[cSelCount]` when you hit the exception. You should be able to see what's wrong with that date string.

Comment: in you previous comment, you mentioned that value is "03-27-2018". and you are trying to parse dd-MM-yyyy format. 27 can not be a month

Comment: @pep  no whitespaces in the string..

Comment: Small note: don't initialize all your variables with null if you're just going to really initialize them five lines below. Just do that in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re generate you code without error. `requiredDateFiled` is `DateTime` so you can use it directly.

```
string[] requiredDateList = new string[] { "03-27-2018", "" };
string[] itemIDList = new string[] { "1", "2" };

int cSelCount = 0;
if (itemIDList != null)
{
   foreach (string itemField in itemIDList)
   {
       DateTime requiredDateFiled = requiredDateList[cSelCount] == "" ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.ParseExact(requiredDateList[cSelCount].ToString(),
                        "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       // THIS LINE IS FOR KNOWLEDGE ONLY NO NEED OF THIS.
       requiredDateFiled = DateTime.ParseExact(requiredDateFiled.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
DateTime dt = String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(date);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d", provider));
```

Try this.

Comment: It would be nice if you describe how this solves the problem.

Comment: @Rufus It would also be nice if it compiled.